# Pushing/committing with the Jenkins git plugin: #Not on any branch (GitHub repo)

Tags: git, github, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am using the [Git Plugin](http://wiki.hudson-ci.org/display/HUDSON/Git+Plugin) of Jenkins and have a Job that needs to commit and push some changes. The git repository I am using is hosted on GitHub. Bear with me, I am somewhat new to git.

However, when I run `git status` or `git commit` it says `# Not on any branch`. If I tell the plugin to use a 'branch specifier', i.e. `origin/master` this doesn't help.

Ho do I get the plugin to behave as if I would have done `git clone` on my desktop?

Comment: you have run `git checkout <some-sha>` probably, so now `git` is looking at that commit, but is not on the tip of any branch. If you've done work where you are now, save it with `git diff > savefile.tmp` and then checkout to the branch you want `git checkout master`, and then apply the work you've done `patch -p1 <  savefile.tmp`, fix any conflicts, and `git commit` your work. Then you can push. If no work is done where you stand, then just checkout  to master and push.

Comment: Excellent, this worked, will you make it an 'answer' so I can mark it solved?

Comment: great, also created an answer ;) thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you have run `git checkout <some-sha>` probably, so now `git` is looking at that commit, but is not on the tip of any branch.

If you've done work where you are now, save it with `git diff > savefile.tmp`
and then checkout to the branch you want: `git checkout master`,
and then apply the work you've done: `patch -p1 < savefile.tmp`,
fix any conflicts, and `git commit` your work.
Then you can `git push`.

If no work is done where you stand, then just checkout to master and push.

Comment: actually I didn't even need to do the patch saving, I just delayed adding the changes to after the `checkout`

Comment: Thanks guys, when I try to run git commands from the shell, it tells me that git cannot be found. Any advice?

Comment: You probably need to install git on the server.  On Ubuntu, for example, this is done through the command 'sudo apt-get install git'.