# git describe --tags does not work on Jenkins pipeline build

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-job-dsl

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10268641/jenkins-git-plugin-git-describe-cannot-describe-anything) which goes in a similar direction but not quite. The problem there was that the tags were simply not pushed correctly.

I am currently using Jenkins to build my python projects using `setuptools_scm`, which basically uses `git describe` to get a (more or less) sensible version number, even if not on a tag. The pipeline is defined using a seed job in JobDSL like this (abbreviated to get to the main points):

```
import BuildProjects

BuildProjects.build_projects.each { def bproject ->
   multibranchPipelineJob("tool/${bproject}") {
      branchSources {
         branchSource {
            source {
               git {
                  id('tool_${bproject}')
                  remote("${BuildProjects.scmBaseLocation}/${bproject}.git")
                  credentialsId(BuildProjects.scmUser)
                  traits {
                     gitBranchDiscovery()
                     gitTagDiscovery()
                     cloneOptionTrait {
                        extension {
                           shallow(false)
                           noTags(false)
                           reference('grmblwrx')
                           timeout(1)
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            }
         }
      }

   }
}
```

Some configuration values are taken from `BuildProjects`.

When running jenkins, I see that it fetches tags:

```
 > git fetch --tags --progress -- ssh://git@git.my-company.net/tools.git +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/* # timeout=1
```

and in fact, I can see the tags when I output them in my Jenkinsfile using an

```
sh "git tag"
```

block. But using

```
sh "git describe --tags"
```

gives

```
fatal: No tags can describe '<Commit hash>'.
Try --always, or create some tags.
```

I read somewhere that this might be due to a sparse checkout: The commits between the tag and the current HEAD might be missing. Upon closer inspection, I found in my logs

```
> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
> git checkout -f <Commit hash> # timeout=10
```

right after the `git fetch` line shown above. It seems that somehow my configuration in the JobDSL is not respected. Any ideas?

Comment: I noticed you have "reference('grmblwrx')", what is this? Also did you try and clean the WS before cloning?

Comment: I understood from the documentation that the reference must not be empty, but if the directory didn't exist, it was not used, so I entered some nonsense-word

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since I posted my question, we updated our Jenkins instance and some plugins, especially the git plugin. For some reason, it "simply works" now. I cannot reproduce the old setting without a lot of trouble, so I cannot easily figure out what caused the "fix".

Answer (score 4):

If is true that since 2018 git plugin 3.4.0, a Jenkins pipeline defaults to clone with a narrow refspec, and without tag.
That was illustrated in [`allegro/axion-release-plugin` issue 195](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin/issues/195), and [documented](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin/commit/eb3e5ac515cfc662f4a180c36c8fd516bfcb2f59) in [`allegro/axion-release-plugin` PR 198](https://github.com/allegro/axion-release-plugin/pull/198).

As seen in [`raster-foundry/raster-foundry` PR 4233](https://github.com/raster-foundry/raster-foundry/pull/4233), check your [`checkout scm` step and its cloneOptions](https://github.com/raster-foundry/raster-foundry/blob/9ab49522c5bd80b540a6e59ff76708251b9fef88/Jenkinsfile#L6-L12):

```
node {
  try {
    // Checkout the proper revision into the workspace.
    stage('checkout') {
      checkout([
        $class: 'GitSCM',
        branches: scm.branches,
        extensions: scm.extensions + [[$class: 'CloneOption', noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false]],
        userRemoteConfigs: scm.userRemoteConfigs
      ])
    }
    ...
```

Try with `noTags: false, reference: '', shallow: false`, and see if the issue persists.

Comment: This is more or less what I did in my JobDSL in the question, so no, this does not work.

Comment: @arne Yes, I didn't read the `cloneOptionTrait` portion of your JobDSL closely enough.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after updating Jenkins from 2.176.2 and git plugin 3.11.0 to Jenkins 2.289.1 and git plugin 4.7.2.

In Manage Jenkins->Configure System->Git Plugin, enable the option "Preserve second fetch during checkout"

[image]

This restored the older git plugin behaviour and "git describe" started working again.

Comment: That didn't help.